# How to keep child from transforming with parent

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Im creating a function to shoot a bullet out of a guns barrel. Im keeping the bullet as a child of the gun in order to have it place at the right position regardless of where the player is facing. However if I shoot while the player is moving the bullet will move relative to the player. How can I remove the relative reference when the bullet has spawn.

```
func creatBullet() {

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
    bullet.zPosition = 4
    bullet.position = CGPoint(x: gun.position.x-1, y: gun.position.y-20)

    //add physics
    gun.addChild(bullet)

    let xDirection = CGFloat(bullet.position.x)
    let yDirection = CGFloat(bullet.position.y + 150)

    let bulletMove = SKAction.moveBy(x: xDirection, y: yDirection, duration: 2)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletMove, SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    bullet.run(sequence)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Apple...

> Converts a point in this node’s coordinate system to the coordinate
>   system of another node in the node tree. Declaration
>
> ```
> func convert(_ point: CGPoint, to node: SKNode) -> CGPoint
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> point  A point in this node’s coordinate system.
>
> node   Another node in the same node tree as this node.
>
> Returns   The same point converted to the other node’s coordinate
>   system.

so I would just use (assuming self is scene)

```
let pos = convert(gun.position, to self)
bullet.position = pos
addChild(bullet)
```

> EDIT

if your object is a child of another object you may have to use convert from and convert to to get the absolute portion

```
pos = convert(convert(gun.position, from: gun.parent!), to: self)
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me Ron, I tried this but when I add it as a child of my gamescene the position is way off. The gun is actually a child of the player not sure if that matters. When I add it as a child of the gun, the position is accurate not sure what Im doing wrong

Comment: Thanks Ron, tried the edited answer but now the position is somewhere off screen.

Comment: You don't put enough code in your question to go any further with this (I don't know how many nested layers there are). I told you the methods needed you will have to play around with them until you can get the right value. People aren't just going to figure it out for you

Comment: thanks again Ron, I appreciate your help. Ill play around with the Convert see what I can get